# Keep connection always open for datatable twoway bind?

Tags: wpf, database, c#-4.0, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF project which includes update/delete/insert operation on many tables. For simplicity, I use a datagrid for each table. The users can operate on these tables directly. Once done, click a button, the tables in database get updated. Twoway bind is perfect in this case. Below code seems working fine.

However, one thing I do not like is: the _DBConnection is always open. It is closed until the form exists. Usually, I always open connection whenever I need to, use it, close it immediately.

So, my question is: is below code the correct way to do the twoway bind?

thanks

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private OleDbConnection _DBConnection;

    private OleDbDataAdapter _DataAdapterAdmin;
    private DataSet _DataSetAdmin;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void InitAdminGrid()
    {
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Admin ORDER BY LastName";
        _DataAdapterAdmin = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, _DBConnection);
        _DataSetAdmin = new DataSet();
        _DataAdapterAdmin.Fill(_DataSetAdmin);

        dgAdministration.BeginInit();
        dgAdministration.DataContext = _DataSetAdmin.Tables[0];
        dgAdministration.Items.Refresh();
        dgAdministration.EndInit();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = clsDataAccess.GetConnectionString();
        _DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        _DBConnection.Open();

        InitAdminGrid();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommandBuilder cmd = new OleDbCommandBuilder(_DataAdapterAdmin);
            _DataAdapterAdmin.Update(_DataSetAdmin);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_DBConnection != null)
        {
            _DBConnection.Close();
            _DBConnection.Dispose();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You can close the connection in `MainWindow_Loaded` and then open for each operation to the database if required.

Comment: no, can't do it. if so, the twoway bind won't work correctly. _DataAdapterAdmin.Update(_DataSetAdmin) will not update table.